# fetch value from two tables with conditions in both table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

select name,id,address  from table1 and table2
table1  column name ,id
table2 column addressId,address,id(fk table1)

Comment: And what is your specific question? Show us your current attempts and let us know which part gives you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

i assumed you have tow tables related with this question.

1. inovoice_details

   - invoice_id
   - inovice (i have a no idea about what is the data stored in this column)
   - date
2. sell_product_details

   - invoice_id
   - product_name
   - rate
   - date

try with this join query

```
SELECT inovoice_details.invoice, sell_product_details.product_name FROM inovoice_details INNER JOIN sell_product_details ON inovoice_details.invoice_id = sell_product_details.invoice_id WHERE inovoice_details.invoice_id =
```

Comment: i assumed you have tow tables related with this question.

1.inovoice_details

invoice_number( unique)
id not null auto increment
date
2.product_details
id same value id
product_name
rate
amount ...this type my table.. i want to fetch data

Comment: Given info is not clear. Please provide the table structures clearly